# VIP URL on SSL is logging out immediately on MVC application Form authentication

Tags: ssl, model-view-controller, forms-authentication, internal-load-balancer, virtual-ip-address

I am facing an issue in MVC 4 C#.NET web application. My web application is hosted on two web server and that two web server is pointing to VIP via Load balancer. when I trying with individual server URL, application is working fine. But when I trying with VIP URL, able to login with application, if I click any menu, application is taking to login screen again. Application is running SSL. I am using Forms Authentication.

Checked load balancer side, server are configured properly. Using sticky session. Machine Key is configured in both web server as same.

Why application is logging out only using VIP URL.

I have traced with Fiddler, getting 302 error. checked cookie during kicking me out, cookie not cleared in browser and on SSL, cookies showing two with same AuthCookie one with content and one without content value. if login again, able to login but click any menu same behaviour, its kicking out.